# Reseting value for atomic long in java 8

Tags: java

How do I reset the value of atomic long back to zero once it reaches the maximum value? As I dont want to generate negative numbers for ID generation

Comment: that would be *a lot* of ID's to generate...

Comment: If you're using it for ID generation, and you expect to overflow long and reset your counter to zero, you would be reallocating IDs you had already used.

Comment: If your ID's may cause a `long` to overflow, why not use a `AtomicReference<BigInteger>`?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, be careful with ID generation and wrapping. Like others have said, you will end up reusing IDs.

```
AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong(0L);
atomicLong.compareAndSet(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0);
```

If atomicLong equals Long.MAX_VALUE, then it gets set back to 0.  If you want to compare and increment at the same time, you will need a synchronize block or Java 8 features.

In Java 8+:

```
long nextId = atomicLong.updateAndGet(current -> current == Long.MAX_VALUE ? 0 : current + 1);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator-

Comment: In a concurrent system, `compareAndSet(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0)` may be unreliable. This call only sets the AtomicLong counter to 0, if the current value is equal to Long.MAX_VALUE. So you have to check after every incrementation and even then you could miss the right moment in a concurrent environment. Example: (a) atomicLong has value Long.MAX_VALUE-1. (b) Thread A calls incrementAndGet, (c) Thread B calls incrementAndGet, (d) If Thread A or B call compareAndSet, they both missed the moment where the counter was equal to Long.MAX_VALUE.